# Github action, maven build fails when using the

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

I try to CI/CD for the jave open source project, which is hosted on github.
When I build the project with maven local, then it works just fine.

But the same maven build fails when triggered inside the github/gitaction environment when building the jave-core target.

https://github.com/a-schild/jave2/blob/develop/jave-core/pom.xml

The special thing, is that I use the org.codehaus.mojo buildnumber-maven-plugin and also the org.codehaus.mojo templating-maven-plugin.

I think it fails because of this, but I am unable to find how to fix it.

Here is the gitaction
https://github.com/a-schild/jave2/blob/master/.github/workflows/maven.yml

And here the error log of the build

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/home/runner/work/jave2/jave2/jave-core' && 'git' 'log' '-n1' '--date-order'
[INFO] Working directory: /home/runner/work/jave2/jave2/jave-core
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/home/runner/work/jave2/jave2/jave-core' && 'git' 'pull' 'https://github.com/a-schild/jave2.git'
[INFO] Working directory: /home/runner/work/jave2/jave2/jave-core
Error:  Provider message:
Error:  The git-pull command failed.
Error:  Command output:
Error:  From https://github.com/a-schild/jave2
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

Comment: Based on what I've looked ... I would say the culprit is `--- buildnumber-maven-plugin:3.0.0:create` ... because you seemed to be executing that in any module and not only in root... there is a configuration for it...also using a lot of very old plugins etc...

Comment: So you think if it is only executed in the root pom.xml it should behave better?

Comment: Yes I'm https://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#getRevisionOnlyOnce (do not update see configuration) also the question is why so many plugins explicitly bound to the lifecycle (for example maven-install-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin) also why not using inheritance of the pom to reduce duplication...etc.. also using wrong versions of plugin (maven-deploy-plugin 3.0.1-M1 which does simply not exist (https://github.com/a-schild/jave2/blob/master/jave-nativebin-arm32/pom.xml)...